# Table 'time_zone_name' was not locked with LOCK TABLES mysql error

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to import an .sql file using cron, and I get this error ...

> ERROR 1100 (HY000) at line 1540: Table 'time_zone_name' was not locked with LOCK TABLES

Can anyone explain what this error means? And BTW, I don't even have a table named 'time_zone_name'.

Also, I was able to get 5/24 rows onto the db with the cron, but it stopped after 5 and I'm getting this error

Comment: What do you mean by "upload a SQL file" exactly? Can you show the table structure? Can you show the command you are using? Can you show lines 5 and 6?

Comment: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9953

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When some tables are locked, CONVERT_TZ requires that the time_zone_name table is locked
too. This is difficult if someone doesn't even have access to that table.

How to repeat:

```
LOCK TABLES
  bugs WRITE;
UPDATE bugs SET
  creation_ts = CONVERT_TZ(creation_ts, "America/New_York", "UTC");
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Results in:
ERROR 1100 (HY000) at line 3: Table 'time_zone_name' was not locked with LOCK TABLES

**Suggested fix:** make CONVERT_TZ not require that table to be locked? Or maybe lock that table automatically.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen - I've edited the answer, this will be visible once it passes moderation.